# Error with string module, python os x

Tags: python, macos, module, osx-lion

I am self-teaching Python from Elkner's How To Think... and have gotten to Chapter 7, strings. I tried to load the string module by typing import string and it seemed to work, however this is what I get:

```
>>> import string
>>> dir (string)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'string']
```

and, confusingly, my help function seems to have died for some related reason:

```
>>> help()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'string']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 458, in __call__
import pydoc
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 57, in <module>
from string import expandtabs, find, join, lower, split, strip, rfind, rstrip
ImportError: cannot import name expandtabs
```

What did I do wrong? How can I fix this? Running Mac OS X 10.7.1.

Answer (score 4):

You've called something "string.py" which is shadowing the actual `string` module. Rename or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

try this for help :

```
import string

help(string)
```

in python you don't need to import string module you can use builtin functions directly .

```
"str".function()
```

and for your target you can use :

```
"str".expandtabs(n)
```

8 is the default number.